# Feasibility of Deploying Solidity Smart Contract on EVM-Compatible Cosmos Chains

Tags: solidity

I would like to inquire if it is feasible to deploy a Solidity smart contract on the following Cosmos chains: Band Protocol, Fetch.AI, Shentu, MediBloc, and Sentinel.

After conducting some research, I discovered that all of these chains are EVM compatible due to Ethermint. However, I was unable to locate any documentation or tutorials on how to deploy Solidity smart contracts on these chains. Additionally, I attempted to add them to Metamask, but was unable to do so despite thinking that all EVM-compatible chains could be added to Metamask.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Yep, if all of them are EVM compatible you can deploy Ethereum smartcontracts on them. The process is the same as if you are deploying on the Ethereum mainnet with the small difference that you should have `json-rpc` provider poining to the selected network instead of the Ethereum network.

Comment: I tried this but still couldn't deploy. Could you please share any tutorials or articles?